# How to cache configuration in Laravel inside Heroku? i.e. build in a different path from runtime

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, build, production-environment

In the Laravel docs it's advised to run `./artisan config:cache` in production to speed things up. That's great with Heroku since every build brings up a new filesystem state, so we don't even have to bother with clearing the cache between deploys.

BUT: if you add that command to your deployment procedure (via Composer for instance) your Laravel app will start crashing, since it'll be looking for files in the now-gone build paths (something like `/tmp/random_string`). If you run `heroku run pwd` you'll notice the runtime app lives on `/app`.

It seems `./artisan config:cache` stores the temporary build path in the cached settings, while the app runs in another path. Is it possible to change the path used in the resulting config cache?

Answer (score 14):

You'd best do this at boot and not at build time.
In order to do so you need to modify you composer.json to add:

```
"warmup": [
    "php artisan config:cache",
    "php artisan route:cache"
],
```

And then modify your procfile to something like `web: composer warmup && $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/`

Credits for the tip goes to David from the Heroku support!

Comment: Kudos to David! How did you get that? You opened a support ticket asking about this?

Comment: Yes, their answer was quite fast. He redirected me to the [Heroku + Symphony doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony#creating-a-procfile)

Comment: Cool! I didn't know they had docs for specific frameworks. If the ticket is still open, ask them to write about that in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel

Comment: I added warmup it inside scripts to work, just for anybody facing that the command not found